# how to run a big query without imposing too much load on the server

Tags: postgresql

I have a query which takes 10 minutes to return data, and it puts a big load on our server. How can run this query without imposing such a big load on the server?

```sql
SELECT m_time_stamp,
       m_wind_speed,
       m_wind_dir,
       m_power,
       m_lim_free_time,
       m_turb_int,
       m_wind_speed_norm,
       m_ntf_wind_speed,
       m_st_run,
       m_availability
FROM t_statistics_10_m
where m_time_stamp>='2014-10-01' and m_turbine_id='xxx.xxx.xx.xx'
```

here is the execution plan

```
Append  (cost=0.00..3175487.56 rows=283409 width=44) (actual time=108.108..127531.966 rows=297644 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=347556 read=319238 written=4
  ->  Seq Scan on t_statistics_10_m  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
        Buffers: shared hit=1
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t_statistics_10_m_2014  (cost=87490.62..131541.09 rows=12100 width=44) (actual time=108.103..112.539 rows=4039 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
        Heap Blocks: exact=1957
        Buffers: shared hit=14873
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_statistics_10_m_2014_pkey  (cost=0.00..87487.60 rows=12100 width=0) (actual time=106.924..107.924 rows=4039 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
              Buffers: shared hit=12916
  ->  Index Scan using t_statistics_10_m_2015_pkey on t_statistics_10_m_2015  (cost=0.56..439353.65 rows=43876 width=44) (actual time=0.02..24624.128 rows=51875 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
        Buffers: shared hit=58116 read=46997
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t_statistics_10_m_2016  (cost=400979.11..553265.63 rows=45818 width=44) (actual time=641.667..28871.488 rows=51745 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
        Heap Blocks: exact=41625
        Buffers: shared hit=60479 read=41627
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_statistics_10_m_2016_pkey  (cost=0.00..400967.66 rows=45818 width=0) (actual time=630.035..630.035 rows=51745 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
              Buffers: shared hit=60479 read=2
  ->  Index Scan using t_statistics_10_m_2017_pkey on t_statistics_10_m_2017  (cost=0.56..552277.59 rows=46713 width=44) (actual time=0.058..18107.842 rows=52248 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
        Buffers: shared hit=64751 read=44575
  ->  Index Scan using t_statistics_10_m_out_of_range_pkey on t_statistics_10_m_out_of_range  (cost=0.14..8.32 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
        Buffers: shared hit=1
  ->  Index Scan using t_statistics_10_m_2018_pkey on t_statistics_10_m_2018  (cost=0.56..503705.67 rows=44849 width=44) (actual time=0.731..34621.832 rows=52174 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
        Buffers: shared hit=64354 read=51926
  ->  Index Scan using t_statistics_10_m_2019_pkey on t_statistics_10_m_2019  (cost=0.56..615897.33 rows=60219 width=44) (actual time=0.037..11791.200 rows=51481 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
        Buffers: shared hit=29768 read=103121
  ->  Index Scan using t_statistics_10_m_2020_pkey on t_statistics_10_m_2020  (cost=0.43..379437.27 rows=29832 width=44) (actual time=0.866..9356.176 rows=34082 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((m_time_stamp >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (m_turbine_id = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'::inet))
        Buffers: shared hit=55213 read=30992 written=4
Planning time: 1.322 ms
Execution time: 127558.480 ms'
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i thought there should be a way to run the query on the background , the reason for why takes so long is the number of data

Comment: Postgres treats all queries as equally important. There is nothing to tell it that a specific query should be processed slower or with less impact than others. But without seeing the execution plan, it is nearly impossible to suggest anything to make the query more efficient

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i have updated my question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated,is it better now?

Comment: How doe the "big load on our server" manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query needs to retrieve a lot of data from the hard disk because it's not cached ("Buffers: ... read=319238" which is about  2.5 GB).

`t_statistics_10_m` seems to be a view that uses a UNION over multiple tables or a partitioned table. The plan for that looks quite reasonable. So I don't think there is much you can do with that query.

I would say your system is simply not powerful enough to cope with it.

If you run that query to export the data to e.g. a flat file (you aren't going to actually *look* at each of the 297644 rows?) then maybe running separate queries on each of the involved tables individually and then combining the on your computer puts less load on the database server.

Comment: yes or run query on partitioned data year by year,thanks

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't offer much for throttling queries.  Make sure it doesn't run in parallel (it already isn't), and if effective_io_concurrency is high, turn it to 0 for this query.

Having indexes which lead with the m_turbine_id column should both make your query faster, and reduce the total load it imposes on the server.  Your current index usage is pretty inefficient.  Except for the 2014 partition, the lead column inequality of the index is always satisfied, and so the index is read entirely and just used as a "skinny table" for filtering, which is not very efficient.

Of course having more indexes will increase the load when inserting or updating rows.